# Kubernetes openshift : Permission denied during deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am using the following snippet to create the deployment

```
oc create -f nginx-deployment.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
      annotations:
        openshift.io/scc: privileged
    spec:
      securityContext:
        priviledged: false
        runAsUser: 0
      volumes:
      - name: static-web-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /home/testFolder
          type: Directory
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html 
          name: static-web-volume
```

I am getting permission denied issue when i try to go inside the  html folder

```
$ cd /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                                                                                                                                                             
$ ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
```

This is easiest sample code as i have similar requirement where i have to read the files from the mounted drives, but that one is failing as well.

I am using kubernetes 1.5 as this is only one available. I am not sure whether the volumes have been mounted or not.
all my dir permissions are set to root as well.

content of /home/testfolder

`0 drwxrwxrwx. 3 root root 52 Apr 15 23:06 . 
4 dr-xr-x---. 11 root root 4096 Apr 15 22:58 .. 
0 drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 6 Apr 15 19:56 ind 
4 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 14 Apr 15 19:22 index.html 
4 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 694 Apr 15 23:06 ordr.yam`

Comment: What method are you using of running OpenShift? Minishift or 'oc cluster up', or full OpenShift install? There are newer versions of OpenShift than 3.5 (Kubernetes 1.5).

Comment: I am using openshift v3.5.5.8
kubernetes v1.5.2. I am using full openshift install.

Comment: What do you get for ``ls -las /home/testFolder`` on the nodes? Was the directory pre-created in each node?

Comment: yeah i created the dir before and trying to mount the dir onto container. added the content of ls -las in the question as well

Comment: What do you get if you run ``id`` inside of the running container?

Comment: uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

Comment: If no one turns up here and can answer, maybe ask on https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo instead.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with following answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember hitting this one in openshift sometime back. It has something to do with SElinux configuration on the host.

Try this at the host server where you mount to your container volume /usr/share/nginx/html.

sudo chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /

Comment: Thanks. it worked. Also ran `oc login -u system:admin` as container automatically assign 99 to user. :) and  chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /home/testFolder